# Chinese Citizen Apply for French Visa (Passport Talent) in USA with H1B Extension Pending Approval

Tags: usa, schengen-visas, long-stay-visas, h1b-visas, french-language

My H-1B visa expired on Aug 28, 2020, and my employer in the US applied for an extension for my H-1B on Aug 13, 2020. Per the 240 days rule, I can legally stay in the US and continue to work while my extension is pending for approval with USCIS. I applied for a French visa last week (Passport Talent) as I'm relocating to France for work. I submitted my original I-797 showing that my H-1B was valid until Aug 28, 2020, the USCIS receipt of Aug 13, 2020 showing that they received my H-1B extension application, and USCIS's explanation of the 240 days rule. I received an email today from the French Embassy asking me to provide additional documents to prove my legal stay in the US. Do you have any advice on what kind of documents I should provide? Thanks!

Comment: We can only help with travel questions here. Questions about residence and work visas can be asked on our sister site, [expatriates.se].